# Adding marker to Google Maps does not work

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(53.385846,-1.471385), 
    map: map,       
    icon: { url:'images/markers.png', size:{height:37,width:32},origin:{x:32,y:0},anchor:{x:15,y:35}
                            },
    draggable:true
});
```

I use this code to add marker to a Google map, but it doesn't work.
When I change the `draggable` parameter value from `true` to `false`, it works.

Is it a bug in Google Maps?

Answer (score 0):

The definition of an [Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon)
 defines it in terms of google.maps.Point and google.maps.Size objects, not anonymous javascript objects as in the code example.  Note the Icon class is a replacement for the newly deprecated [MarkerImage](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerImage) class.

anchor  [Point](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Point)

origin  [Point](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Point)

scaledSize  [Size](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Size)

size    [Size](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Size)

This might work better (not tested):

```
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(53.385846,-1.471385), 
  map: map,       
  icon: { 
          url:'images/markers.png', 
          size: new google.maps.Size(37,32},
          origin: new google.maps.Point(32,0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(15,35)
        },
  draggable:true
});
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_marker.html)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var triangle = null;
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.385846, -1.471385);

function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
    center: myLatLng,
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: {
      url: 'http://www.geocodezip.com/mapIcons/marker1.png',
      size: new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 34)
    },
    draggable: true
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="height: 400px; width:500px;"></div>
```

Comment: yes, I know it. But I have to get the icon object from the server side as by Json string, like { url:'images/markers.png', size:{height:37,width:32},origin:{x:32,y:0},anchor:{x:15,y:35}                     }.
as a Json string I can't serialize “new google.maps.Size”。

Comment: 1. Your requirement to get the object from the server side won't make it work, you will probably need to translate your JSON data into the appropriate google.maps objects, what do you do for the google.maps.LatLng?  2. I don't know why it works when draggable is false, but that doesn't solve your problem.